# How to add a field in the mongoDB query representing a total figure

Tags: mongodb-query, aggregate

I have a mongodb query

```
[  
    {$group: { 
        _id: '$status',
        count: {$sum: NumberInt(1)}
    }}
]
```

The query returns the following result:

```
[
    { _id: "A", count: 22 },
    { _id: "B", count: 33 },
    { _id: "C", count: 44 }
]
```

Based on the above, I need to add a new field "totalCount" (e.g. 22 + 33 + 44 = 99) as in the following:

```
[
    { _id: "A", count: 22, totalCount: 99 },
    { _id: "B", count: 33, totalCount: 99 },
    { _id: "C", count: 44, totalCount: 99 }
]
```

Any help or clue is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You have to make use of `$facet` stage to create multiple instances of aggregation, calculate the total count in a different stage and finally merge into a single output.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$facet": {
      "totalCount": [
        {
          "$group": {
            "_id": null,
            "totalCount": {
              "$sum": "$count"
            }
          },
          
        },
        
      ],
      "root": [
        {
          "$replaceRoot": {
            "newRoot": "$$ROOT"
          }
        },
        
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    "$unwind": "$root"
  },
  {
    "$replaceRoot": {
      "newRoot": {
        "$mergeObjects": [
          "$root",
          {
            "$arrayElemAt": [
              "$totalCount",
              0
            ]
          }
        ],
        
      }
    }
  },
  
])
```

[Mongo Sample Execution](https://mongoplayground.net/p/xe1kFIq1oAB)

Comment: Hi hiharsha36, I am truly excited to have your response. I even tried with my little knowledge to solve the problem with $facet and gave up. I will try your solution and come back soon. Best Regards

Comment: Hi hiharsha36, your query worked perfectly to resolve my issue, many many thanks and best regards - Mehedi

Comment: @MehediSalah glad that it helped you out. Upvote the answer and mark it as solution so that it will help others facing similar problem